# Override Extended Class's Method Visability

Tags: php, oop

Is there a way to override an extended classes method visibility without overriding the whole method?

```
class A
{
    public function perform()
    {
        // Do a bunch of stuff that you don't want to override.
    }
}

class B extends A
{

    /*
    * Change perform()'s viability from public
    * to protected without re-coding the whole method.
    */
}

// You can not do this.
$b = new B();
$b->perform();
```

Comment: Its called reflection, see the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionmethod.setaccessible.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a protected method that simply calls the parent method:

```
class B extends A
{
    protected function perform() {
        parent::perform();
    }
}
```